# SQL: Best way to write a condition that checks the value of a variable when the variable could be null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am writing a pgplsql function in which I have a variable `var` that could be `NULL` or valorized. In a later query I do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = var
```

that, in case of a NULL var, becomes

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = NULL
```

So the query fails with NULL, because, as [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-comparison.html) says,

> The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal

I resolved it with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
( CASE WHEN var IS NULL THEN column IS NULL ELSE column = var END ) = TRUE
```

But I am unsure wether this is the best way to resolve the question... do you have any good alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS NOT DISTINCT FROM var
```

Answer (score 1):

If `var` has a value of NULL, do you really only want to select records having a column value of NULL? Or would you want to treat it as a 'select all'/'do not restrict'?

If the latter applies, then an approach like this would work. (This is pseudocode as I am native to MSSQL.)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(var IS NULL AND column = column) OR column = var
```

Comment: `var` has not a value of `NULL`, `var` COULD have (or not) a value of `NULL` :) Anyway your solution is correct, so +1. Thank you!